# Scipy `fmin_cg` args are not match with my functions args

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-regression

I am trying to build a linear regression model and find optimal values using `fmin_cg` optimizer.
I have two functions for this job. First `linear_reg_cost` which is cost function and second `linear_reg_grad` which is gradient of cost function. This functions both have same argument.

```
def hypothesis(x,theta):
    return np.dot(x,theta)
```

Cost function:

```
def linear_reg_cost(x_flatten, y, theta_flatten, lambda_, num_of_features,num_of_samples):
    x = x_flatten.reshape(num_of_samples, num_of_features)
    theta = theta_flatten.reshape(n,1)
    loss = hypothesis(x,theta)-y
    regularizer = lambda_*np.sum(theta[1:,:]**2)/(2*m)
    j = np.sum(loss ** 2)/(2*m) 
    return j
```

Gradient function:

```
def linear_reg_grad(x_flatten, y, theta_flatten, lambda_, num_of_features,num_of_samples):
    x = x_flatten.reshape(num_of_samples, num_of_features)
    m,n = x.shape
    theta = theta_flatten.reshape(n,1)
    new_theta = np.zeros(shape=(theta.shape))
    loss = hypothesis(x,theta)-y
    gradient = np.dot(x.T,loss)
    new_theta[0:,:] = gradient/m
    new_theta[1:,:] = gradient[1:,:]/m + lambda_*(theta[1:,]/m)
    return new_theta
```

and `fmin_cg`:

```
theta = np.ones(n)

from scipy.optimize import fmin_cg
new_theta = fmin_cg(f=linear_reg_cost, x0=theta, fprime=linear_reg_grad,args=(x.flatten(), y, lambda_, m,n))
```

Note: I flatten `x` as input and retrieve in the cost and gradient function as matrix.

the output error:

```
<ipython-input-98-b29c1b8f6e58> in linear_reg_grad(x_flatten, y, theta_flatten, lambda_, num_of_features, num_of_samples)
  1 def linear_reg_grad(x_flatten, y, theta_flatten, lambda_,num_of_features, num_of_samples):
 ----> 2     x = x_flatten.reshape(num_of_samples, num_of_features)
       3     m,n = x.shape
       4     theta = theta_flatten.reshape(n,1)
       5     new_theta = np.zeros(shape=(theta.shape))

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (2,12)
```

Note: `x.shape = (12,2)`, `y.shape = (12,1)` ,`theta.shape = (2,)`. So `num_of_features =2` and `num_of_samples=12`. But error shows that my input `x` is parsing instead of `theta`. Why this happening even when I explicitly assigned `args` in `fmin_cg`? And how I should solve this problem?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: The source code and datasets [link](https://github.com/Nikronic/Coursera-Machine-Learning/tree/master/Week%206%20-%20Regularized%20Linear%20Regression%20and%20Bias%20v.s.%20Variance)

Answer (score 1):

All of your implementations are correct but you have a little mistake.
Be inform to pass arguments in order for both of your functions.
Your problem is the order of `num_of_feature` and `num_of_samples`. You can replace their position with each other in `linear_reg_grad` or `linear_reg_cost`. Of course you should change this order in `scipy.optimize.fmin_cg`, `args` argument.

**Second important thing is, `x` as first argument in `fmin_cg` is the variable you want to update each time and find the optimal one. So in your solution, `x` in `fmin_cg` must be `theta` not your `x` which is your input.**